# Is there a library for MSR605X that works with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lib

I have been trying to locate a working library for the MSR605X magnetic card reader/writer. At time of writing, I have tried five separate libraries. Only two of these were explicitly for the 605X the other three were for the older 605. All the libraries I have tried either did nothing at all or errored before completing a command (can't figure out the errors either).

I am running Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ the MSR605X communicates via a USB connection.

So far the library that seems to be most complete is: https://pypi.org/project/msrx/

However, I can not get this library to read or write (either nothing happens or I get a Serial exception "cannot reconfig port).

Any help or links to documentation for this reader is welcome.

EDIT: Adding the commands ran with the above library

```
msrx -D /dev/input/event4 read
msrx -D /dev/input/jso0 read
```

The -D is to specify the device path (default is /dev/ttyUSB0 which doesn't exist on my system). I obtained the above two paths by searching for USB serial devices then matching the search result to the device ID which I obtained from lsusb.

Running these commands results in a serial exception (could not reconfig port) which I assume means that I have the wrong device path. I have also checked for any tty* device paths that are changed when I plug in the reader. I consistently get a permission denied error whenever trying to run the above commands with a tty* device path (I am root on this system).

Comment: Show what code you tried with that library. Otherwise, just asking for recommendations is defined as off-topic for SO.

Comment: There is no code to post. The library has commands that I ran. I'll update with that

Answer (score 0):

`msrx` author here — MSR605 requires an external 9V power injected into its cable (via the barrel jack port), otherwise it won't power up properly.